# full spectrum lamp in Australia

Tags: color

I want to purchase a full spectrum or solar quality lamp. I am in Melbourne, Australia. I have heard that an architect lamp with Solux or Ott bulb will be a good solution. Can you recommend a great quality lamp for happy eyes and colour accuracy? If this is the wrong forum, please suggest somewhere else.

Comment: I'll try ergonomics in workplace stack exchange, failing that whirlpool broadband forums, they have good q&a on most any topic.

Comment: "where to buy X" are off-topic, specially on GD.SE

Comment: I didn't ask "where to buy". It's all good, I decided to manufacture my own lamps using multiple colours of incandescent bulbs, independently dimmable. Like a retro-style Philips Hue, with pleasant, quality light.

Comment: cool. I just realized, maybe you could ask the guys at the [photography.se] site, they might be more acquainted with lighting than us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't know are you going to shoot photos or do you want color accurate light to show something (=an art gallery, a shop etc...). Or do you need light to do some work?

Photo shooting can accept low color temperature lamps, say only 3500K which look yellowish, but haven't spectrum peaks nor gaps. Those peaks and gaps spoil more or less the colors.

Gaps and peaks in the spectrum are caused by atomic light creation processes which in leds and fluorescent lamps are accumulated to certain material dependent sparsely spaced wavelengths.

Only thermal light emission has continuous spectrum, but there are developed fluorescent materials which partially convert monochromatic or split spectrum light to more uniform spectral density. Without them leds and fluorescent lamps would be totally useless for color photography and comparing colors.

Cameras can be adjusted for certain color temperature, but that doesn't help if the color rendering is inaccurate. There's a measure number CRI (=color rendering index) for comparing how much there's peaks and gaps in the spectrum.

Incandescent lamps have continuous spectrum. Their luminosity and color tempeatures vary, but their CRI is virtually 100% like daylight's.  Their limitations are heat, high power consumption and much shorter life especially in high color temperatures and luminosity levels. Search for data about color temperature and color rendering index (CRI). They affect as well to photography, working efficiency and general comfort. By understanding well the luminosity measures, color temperature and CRI you should be able to judge if your purchase candidates make light which is usable for your purposes. We cannot make purchase recommendations in this site. But at least your candidates seem to have CRI > 90%. Less than 90% would be recognizably bad.

I must add still something: Incandescent lamps have strong nearly visible infrared emission. We cannot see it, but some common color materials reflect it well. Because ordinary cameras catch also well near-IR, some colors can look hopelessly too red in the photos. That's a problem when one tries to take a photo of certain old paintings. He can say "what makes this painting red in a photo, I can swear it was blue!"

Ultraviolet emission of white leds and fluorescent lamps can also be harmful if the camera happens to catch it due the lack of internal UV blocking layer in the sensor. It makes things too blue and also hazy because the lens doesn't work properly in such short wavelengths. I have not used any modern camera which has harmfully non-UV protected sensor, but that doesn't prove they are nonexistent. The opposite: I have seen some DSLR cameras recommended for reflected UV photography.